# Как спарсить id человека с его страницы вк? Python

Tags: python, парсер, вконтакте

Как спарсить id человека с его страницы вк?Или полyчить дрyгим способом, но через python

Comment: bs4, selenium, что за парсер?

Comment: bs4 + requests парсинг

Comment: https://vk.com/id100 из таких ссылок надо получать?

Comment: В ссылке на страницy не показан id, там то что человек сам написал, и надо как-то полyчить id но через python

Comment: Вы может привести пример, как найти этот ID на сайте?

Comment: через код страницы можно

Comment: <a href="/write170529114" onclick="return checkEvent(event) ? true : showWriteMessageBox(event, 170529114)" onmouseover="stManager.add(['wide_dd.js', 'wide_dd.css', 'writebox.css', jsc('web/writebox.js'), jsc('web/emoji.js'), 'notifier.css'])" class="button_link cut_left"> После write стоит id

Comment: @Амин, используйте `vk-api` (https://github.com/python273/vk_api) иначе, думаю, придется авторизовываться на сайте vk, чтобы увидеть данные профилей

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

page_link = 'https://vk.com/id1' # здесь пишем нужную страничку
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language':'ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'DNT':'1'
}

# заходим "в гости" к пользователю
page = get(page_link, headers=headers) 
soup = BS(page.text, 'lxml')
# находим ссылку на фото профиля
href = soup.find('a', {'id':'profile_photo_link'}).get('href')
# отрезаем ненужную часть
start = href.find('photo')+len('photo')
end = href.find('_')
user_id = href[start:end]
print(user_id)
```

Comment: Не работает способ, на акке https://vk.com/joinedthegame

Comment: @Амин, на скрытых профилях он не будет работать